# How do I make MySQL, PHP, & Apache run off of my SSD? (Linux)

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, php, apache-2.4, ssd

I'm fairly new to the whole Linux Server thing but one of my websites has grown to the point that I'm moving to a dedicated hardware virtual-server instead of using a web-hosting service.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and I've installed Apache, MySQL, and PhP through the apt-get commands. In order to get to my SSD i simply navigate to `/ssd/`

How do I make sure that all of my web stuff is running on the SSD and not the HDD the operating system is installed on.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure that your document root is after /ssd on your VirtualHost definition.

example:

```
DocumentRoot /ssd/wwwroot
```

also for mysql you would need to edit the /etc/my.cnf file to have

```
[mysqld] 
datadir=/ssd/mysqldata
```

Comment: The DocumentRoot being found in one of the conf files usually under /etc/apache2

Comment: in ubuntu this should be the main configuration file
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Comment: From memory that's a symbolic link to /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf

But yes you should find the DocumentRoot directive inside it. That determines where the files are that get served up.

Comment: This is only a small part of the answer, if "all of my web stuff" includes the database.